# Python "if" statement. Ignore specific input if certain criteria is already met

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

I need to add a line to this so that if `octave == 1` and `pygame.K_s` is pressed it will ignore the input. Currently it crashes because it's expecting a > 0 value or something like that. I've tried adding 
`if octave == 1 and even.key == pygame.k_s: octave +=1`
and it does keep it from crashing, but then I can no longer go back to octave 1 once I pass it. Here's the portion of the code I'm having issues with.

```
        if event.key == pygame.K_a: octave += 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_s: octave -= 1
        if event.key == pygame.K_q: scale += 0.005
        if event.key == pygame.K_w: scale -= 0.005
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if mode == 1: mode = 2
            elif mode == 2: mode = 3
            elif mode == 3: mode = 1
```

A basic run down of what the code does, when the a key is pressed it moves up one octave, when the s key is pressed, it moves down one octave, but I need it to ignore the keypress if it is already at octave 1 because there is no octave 0 variable
-Solved

Comment: Not necessarily the issue, but have you tried: `if (octave == 1) and (even.key == pygame.k_s): octave +=1`. This is to be extra sure there are no chained comparisons.

Comment: Tried just now and no change :/

Comment: OK, then I suggest you need to provide a *minimal* example that we can *run ourselves*. As such, there is likely nothing verifiable for us to test / fix.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about how to do that. This is a two part code, and isn't my code.

Comment: a basic run down of what the code does, when the a key is pressed it moves up one octave, when the s key is pressed, it moves down one octave, but I need it to ignore the keypress if it is already at octave 1 because there is no octave 0 variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `max(octave, 1)` after you decrement the value, so that it stays >= 1.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_s:
    octave -= 1
    octave = max(octave, 1)
```

Comment: I just got it to work using `if (octave < 2) and (event.key == pygame.K_s): octave = 1`
but that looks more organized, heh, may give that a shot also.

Answer (score 1):

When checking for keypress 's' you can add another verification for octave value equals to 1 , i.e.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_s: 
   if octave >= 1
      octave -= 1
```

Hope I understand the problem correctly.